# Delete files throughout a tree but only if they're in a named subfolder

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line

I want to use `del` to delete files of a specific type within a large tree but ONLY IF they are in a named subfolder.

For example, for these files:

```
\test\sample.jpg
\test\fred\pics\sample.jpg
\test\jenny\sample.jpg
\test\fred\pics\sample.jpg
```

I want to run a command from the test folder \test\ to delete *.jpg (presumably `del` using the `/S` switch) but only the ones that are in the folders called `\pics`.

**Important:** the parent folders (in this example 'jenny' and 'fred') are unknown.

So, a successful run would leave this:

```
\test\sample.jpg
\test\jenny\sample.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `for /r X:\path\test /D %A in (pics.?) do @Del "%~fA\*.jpg"` the dummy wildcard `.?` is needed for the command to work.

Sample tree /F before:

```
> tree /F
└───test
    │   sample.jpg
    ├───fred
    │   └───pics
    │           sample.jpg
    └───jenny
        │   sample.jpg
        └───pics
                sample.jpg
```

and after running the cmd line:

```
> tree /F
└───test
    │   sample.jpg
    ├───fred
    │   └───pics
    └───jenny
        │   sample.jpg
        └───pics
```

In a batch file you have to double the `%A` -> `%%A`

```
@Echo off
for /r X:\path\test /d %%A in (pics.?) do Del "%%~fA\*.jpg"
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked a treat.

Now I'd like to change it so that instead of *.jpg it deletes everything.

In theory that's *.* except the result is a query ("Are you sure?") and that's not great when I'm running it as a silent batch file.

The solution is to use the /Q switch here:

for /r C:\TREE /d %%A in (pics.?) do Del /Q "%%~fA\*.*"

Comment: See `del /?` There is the argum.ent `/Q` to suppress that message